# Elementor Footer does not stick to bottom of page

Tags: wordpress, footer, elementor

I'm currently working on a website using Elementor. I tried integrating a Footer using a separate plugin (Elementor Footer&Header), however, the footer didn't stick to the bottom of the page if there was only little or no content.

As this seems to be a common issue, I solved the problem by adding the following code:

```
div.footer-width-fixer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Now, the footer sticks to the bottom of the page, however, there 2 other problems:

1. The footer overlaps with the content in the bottom of the page (see attached image)
2. The footer is sticky, although I didn't set it up to be so. I only want the footer to appear at the bottom of the page, not while the visitor is scrolling.

Any ideas how to solve this? Thank you!

Best Regards,

Maurice ( :

[overlapping-footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qlpn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its tough to tell if the footer is actually overlapping another sentence (I only speak english so I cant tell if the sentence ends or read it at all). But it looks like its only overlapping the padding on the button and its just snug to the text content.

You could try to add either

```
padding-top: {desired pixel amount}px;
```

or

```
margin-top: {desired pixel amount}px;
```

to the footer and see if that does the trick.

As for the position sticky, If your familiar with the inspect element feature in google chrome; you can see what the class selector is that is applying the sticky to the element and then you should be able to write a bit of css to overwrite that fairly easily!

Comment: The margin - solution works! Apparently I don't know how to figure out the specific code section which makes the footer sticky as I don't have enough experience, neither with css nor with the editor.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to make the footer "unsticky" with code?

Comment: If your familliar with resourses like dev inspector (when you right click on an element and then select inspect in the web browser) you should be able to find the footer and it will show you the css selector that is giving it the class of `position: sticky;` once you find the selector you should have no issues over writing it with something like `position: static;` or `position: relative;` noting that your css selector will have to be "more important" than the existing one so you can add `!important` or have a more specific selector to restyle.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem a few times but I simply fix this by setting the height of the section to either "fit to screen" or the VH to 100 - the header height (If you use a transparent header). I hope this has helped you and if you have any questions don't mind asking!

Comment: Your solution works as far as it actually removes the sticky footer and it now only appears on the bottom...however, this only applies to pages with content - pages with no or little content are exempt from that and the header is somewhere in the middle of the page. Applying code to make it stick to the bottom overwrites the min. height and the footer becomes sticky again...thanks for the help!